# EXTJS4 -how to add editable checkbox column in a grid?

Tags: extjs4

Please let me know, how to add checkbox column in a grid.

I tried the [following](http://ext4all.com/post/extjs-4-readonly-checkbox-column). But its read only `checkbox`.

Should I use `checkboxModel`? if so, then please let me have the complete code

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, an Ext4 example matching any data element:

```
{
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
    header: 'My Checkbox column',
    dataIndex: 'myBooleanFieldThatMatchesTheModelFieldOfMyGridStore',
    listeners: {// In case you want to perform a specific action on click...
        checkChange: me.onCheckChange
    },
    flex: 1
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of a grid with a checkbox.

```
var sm = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel');
var grid2 = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: //
    selModel: sm,
    columns: //[]
    columnLines: true,
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    frame: true,
    title: 'Framed with Checkbox Selection',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: Your example offers a checkbox all right, but in the context of selecting things! While the original question clearly shows he wants a checkbox that corresponds a data field. :-)  Your attempt is much appreciated nonetheless :-)

Comment: @Lawrence Thank you for your constructive criticism. It's 3 years ago and the OP did not respond at all. It is not clear what he is asking (I don't know where you find the information about "he wants a checkbox that corresponds a data field").

Comment: Actually, I might have to apologize because indeed, when rereading the question, it is not clear as you say. Perhaps it is me who misunderstood hahaha :-)